# How can I declare the Json variable in this case on swiftUI

Tags: swiftui

It cannot show the result, anyone knows?

```swift
struct Course: Hashable, Codable {
   let id:String
   let display:String
}

class ViewModel: ObservableObject{
@Published var courses: [Course]= []

    func fetch(){
        guard let url = URL(string:"https://www.i-design.hk/api/menu/userMenuRequest.php?type=userMenu&action=l&userId=200380")else{
            return
        }
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { [weak self]data,_, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                return
            }
```

I have tried many times to change the code, but I cannot show the JSON string correctly. Anyone can help me?

Comment: This example is not complete. Show the part where you try to decode the response. What is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

when the response came from API it came in form of JSON and you need to decode that JSON so that can easily read by swift, so you should decode the response like that and when you get the response you should assign the data to the courses variable so that it will published to the view

```
struct Course: Hashable, Codable {
    let id:String
    let display:String
     }

class ViewModel: ObservableObject{
  @Published var courses: [Course]= []
  @Published var error: String = ""



   func fetch(){
       guard let url = URL(string:"https://www.i- 
        design.hk/api/menu/userMenuRequest.php? 
        type=userMenu&action=l&userId=200380")else{
        return
    }
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { [weak 
     self]data,_, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {
            return
        }
        do{
        let ResponseResult = try JSONDecoder().decode([Course], from: data)
                    courses = ResponseResult
       }catch(let error){
                    error = error.localizedDescription
        }
      }
```